# Create a new user on a read only Azure SQL Server geo replica

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm looking at creating a read only geo replica of a production Azure SQL Server database on a new azure db server in a different resource group.  The idea is offload reporting queries to the replica so the production database doesn't get bogged down with long running queries.

Before I do this I was wondering if I can add new users to the read only replica that do not get overwritten in the replication process?  I'd rather have them exist only on the replica, but if that isn't possible I guess the process is to add logins and users to the source database, get their SIDs, and then add them to the master in the replicated database server.  I was hoping to avoid that.

Thanks.

Comment: SQL Database had containment enabled, so it would be enough to add the user on the "primary" (no need for a login in the first place).

Comment: I honestly can't tell from the question if it's for Azure SQL DB or a VM. @Infocyde would you add a tag or update the question to remove the ambiguity?